# Scala: Calling function dynamically

Tags: scala

I am very new to scala.

I am using rscala to integrate with R functions.
For example, I am using the following method to call an R function and retreive a String value.

**Method Signature:**

> def invokeS0(function: Reference, args: Any*): String

**Method Implementation**

```
val v= rc.invokeS0("doPred","lemmas"->"Communicate,Design,Java,","frequency"->"3,3,1")
```

**My Problem**

However, rc.invokeS0 can call ANY function and thus have ANY number of arguments.

I'm thinking of building a wrapper method that takes the function name as a String and arguments as a Map. Perhaps something like this:

```
private def invokeRStringFunction(functionName: String = "testFunction", args: Map[String,String]): Unit =
{
    /**Iterate through map to generate following code*/
    val v= rc.invokeS0(functionName,mapKey1->mapValue1,mapKey2->mapValue2 etc etc)
}
```

But I am not sure how to write the code given that the number of arguments is dynamic. Frankly, I am not sure if it is possible, but thought I would check, just in case.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the `Map[String, String]` into a `Seq[(String, String)]` with `args.toSeq`, and then use the [`_*` ascription](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/functions-and-closures.html#8.8) to pass it as a sequence of arguments instead of just one.

```
def invokeRStringFunction(functionName: String, args: Map[String, String]): Unit
= rc.invokeS0(functionName, args.toSeq: _*)
```

Comment: Thanks! how will that handle the ' -> ' operator between parameter name and parameter value?

Comment: It''s not an operator. Scala has very few operators. `->` is simply a method, defined by implicit conversion on `Any`, that creates a pair out of two values. `a -> b` means the same thing as `(a, b)` but looks nicer. A `Map[A, B]`, when turned into a `Seq`, becomes a bunch of key-value pairs `(A, B)`.

Comment: I'll give it a try! Thanks a million. I'll be sure to upvote and accept when working